# How to monitor a long process in a JSF 2/Primefaces/JBoss application

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x

I have a JSF 2/Primefaces/JBoss application that has to run some long term processes from time to time. Specification says that once the process is started, its progress has to be monitored, showing the occurrence of intermediary phases of it.

The total count of steps is retrieved in the beginning and a progress bar has to show the process evolution and and estimate of the remaining time, based on the statistics calculated during the process execution. It's not like only showing that something is happening, but actually showing how much the process still remains to be done.

Even if the user closes the page, the process has to continue and if the user gets back to the page, it has to show the current progress status of the process. If the process is already finished, then some informations should be presented, like the number of objects processed and, the total time taken and some other statistics, like the object that took longer to be processed.

How to accomplish that in a JSF 2/Primefaces/JBoss application?

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed... So a comment instead: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=40905 Hint: use PrimeFaces Push

Comment: [Server Sent Events](https://www.bing.com/search?q=java+server+sent+events&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) are a natural fit for your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question can be broken down into two main problems. 
1. How to log and track the status of a job.
2. How to present this information in the UI.

Depending on your requirements and your JBoss version, you may want to consider using a [managed thread](http://www.javabeat.net/creating-managed-threads-using-managedthreadfactory-java-ee-7-part-3/). You must decide how you will track the process steps. You could log each completed step in a database or keep it in memory. How will errors be handled? What if the process does not complete? Once you have these back end design decisions completed and implemented you just need to figure out what you want the UI to be like.

As mentioned in the comments section, [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) offers a couple different options such as polling or server sent events. If you are using polling leaving the page and revisiting should already be handled by presenting the result for any point in time. You would then just need to refresh the view on an interval.